How do I get dotnet watch run to run additional targets?
I've added tailwind to my project but can't get it to work with dotnet watch run. As it stands now I have to an actual build to see new css file. The target I have setup is the one below
  <Target Name="Tailwind" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="pnpm run css:build"/>
  </Target>

This works perfectly fine, but it will not run whenever I make a code change under dotnet watch run. Any ideas on how it should be done?

you might need to extend list of files being watched - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-8.0#customize-files-list-to-watch

@YehorAndrosov, the problem is not that the files aren't watched, it is that the target isn't run at all. I want that target to run on changes in cshtml files, and those are already watched and I can see it restarts without the target being triggered.

I see, usually I don't use msbuild events for this. way easier to do it using visual studio extension, rider file watcher or you can spin node script up to watch for changes
